# SOAP vs REST: How to tell the difference in the server code?

Tags: c#, rest, soap

Let's say I have two service: one being SOAP and the other being REST. How would I determine which of the two is which by only looking at their interfaces.

I searched a bit on this subject, but the results I get are mostly on what the differences are between the two in general. There wasn't anything too specific for differentiating the two in code.

The only thing I have to go on this is that REST services tend to have the keyword WebInvoke or a URL or something a long those lines, but I am not sure how accurate that is.

Comment: What aspect of the two do you care about? The calling code is quite different, so I don't know what part is not obvious.

Comment: REST will use GET/POST/DELETE calls, SOAP works by sending envelopes (xml typically) to a listener... should be pretty obvious.

Comment: Hit F5, see what happens? Look for referenced assemblies? Check the attributes?

Comment: @JohnSaunders If I was to have a SOAP interface and a REST interface, how would I tell which is which? I am referring to the method signatures and any attributes or other related things that will differentiate the two.

Comment: @CodeCaster Besides the attributes, is there any other way to differentiate the two. As for attributes, what are must have attributes for each in all services?

Comment: REST doesn't _have_ method signatures. It doesn't have methods. REST just uses HTTP, like the `WebClient` or `WebRequest` classes. If the code creates an instance of an object, then calls methods on it, and if the object is just a proxy class, then it's SOAP.

Comment: Just search for _any_ attribute, then search the web for it. Common ones are OperationContract and WebGet. It would really help if you explain the actual situation.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am looking at two similar interfaces, one is for SOAP and one is for REST. They both have the OperationContract attribute, so I can;t use that to distinguish between which is which. The REST interface has the WebInvoke attribute, which is pretty much the only difference. I was originally asking you whether you knew common attributes for each, not for both. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah you can see `ServiceContract` and `OperationContract` if it's a WCF service with SOAP (basic/wsHttp) and REST (webHttp) bindings. Depending on the framework used, this may or may not be the case.

Comment: @JohnSaunders This is a block of code in the interface: 
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    Method = "GET",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "/ActivateOverflow?" + "id={id}&" + "type={type})]
    string ActivateOverflow(string id, string type);
Sorry for the formatting, not entirely sure how it works in comments. I am not sure what the last line is called, but I called it a method signature. What is the correct term?

Comment: What do you believe the distinction means? What aspect of REST are you comparing to what aspect of SOAP? In other words, why do you care? Also, are you asking about the difference on the client, or on the server?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I am not too familiar with either, but I thought it be nice to know some distinguishing features between the two from the code as opposed to the technical difference if that makes any sense at all. I wanted to know more on the server side.

Comment: See the "Related" list over on the right side of this question? That should have some helpful links for you.